# Android redirect uri

Tags: android, redirect, instagram-api

I'm working with the instagram API and I don't understand what I should put in for the redirect api. At the moment I simply put in https://127.0.0.1

But I dont really understand. Also, once I get the allow/cancel screen and I press allow it gives me an error saying that I cant go to that address but I can also see the authorization code appended on to the address. So how can i redirect back from my redirect uri? How can I tell android that after user clicks allow to come back into the app use the code for further authentication?

Im sure you will say something like make my own custom scheme/ intent filters etc but please be a little more supportive im new and I dont understand and I did do research on them.

My on resume method is below

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // the intent filter defined in AndroidManifest will handle the return from ACTION_VIEW intent
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(redirectUri)) {
            // use the parameter your API exposes for the code (mostly it's "code")
            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
            if (code != null) {
                // get access token
                LoginService loginService =
                        ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, clientId, clientSecret);
                AccessToken accessToken = loginService.getAccessToken(code, "authorization_code");
            } else if (uri.getQueryParameter("error") != null) {
                // show an error message here
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my manifest snippet dealing with intent filters:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="redirecturi"
                    android:scheme="your" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to setup an event listener on the browser view and check for `code` in URL param if the URL is equal to the redirect_uri, and then make POST request to the auth URL using the `code` and `client_secret` as documented in Instagram authentication

something like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String code = url.getQueryParameter("code");
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: How exactly do that? Im posting my on resume below as well as my manifest snippets for you to have a look.

Comment: also what is my redirect uri? Can it be anythingm can i put google.com when i register my app

Comment: furthermore i just registered another app and put my own website as the redirect uri. Sure enough this time it redirected back to mywebsite with the code parameter. The only problem is I dont want to go to my website i want it back in the app.

Comment: I furthermore changed  android:host="redirecturi"
                                     android:scheme="your" /> where I changed your to http and redirecturi to the one from the address bar but it still wouldnt go back to my app

Comment: lastly.... by shear trial and error.
My redirect uri was this = http://127.0.0.1

in my manifest I edited it to look like this :

<data
android:host="127.0.0.1"
android:scheme="http" />
When I did this after authorization I girst got redirected to http://127.0.0.1/?code
I got a webpage not available error. When I clicked on the link however it prompted me to open either using my loginactivity or with browser. If i click in login activity I finally found my way back in the app. But. Why is it doing this? Why isnt it going back into my app so I can then extract the code and make my post request

Comment: Thank you, I now have managed to get the code/authentication token. Im struggling with POST command using retrofit. How can I make an interface and generate a service? Do you have any experience with that? For example if i want to get pictures related to a tag: I need to post this https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN But how exactly do I set it up.

Comment: u have to do a GET for that

Comment: yeah i thought so too just the instagram documentations got me confused. anyways im still struggling with retrofit argh